# While sending SMS, application is crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I want to send sms using below code in iPhone 4, but the application is crashing due to this code only.

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
                MFMessageComposeViewController *smsComposerController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
                [smsComposerController setBody:@"First SMS"];
                smsComposerController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"9886333333",@"9980444444",nil];
                smsComposerController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                [smsComposerController release];
            }
```

I am new for SMS sending , so can any one help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  `[self presentModalViewController:smsComposerController animated:YES];`
in your code to send the sms.

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
            MFMessageComposeViewController *smsComposerController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            [smsComposerController setBody:@"First SMS"];
            smsComposerController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"9886333333",@"9980444444",nil];
            smsComposerController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
           [self presentModalViewController:smsComposerController animated:YES];
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're `autoreleasing` and then `releasing` again `smsComposerController`.

Just release it once. You can review you memory management rules [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
            MFMessageComposeViewController *smsComposerController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            [smsComposerController setBody:@"First SMS"];
            smsComposerController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"9886333333",@"9980444444",nil];
            smsComposerController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [smsComposerController release];          <-------------- THIS IS YOUR ERROR
        }
```

You should not release an auto-release object.